# Trouble expanding image in samsung s8

Tags: android, image, user-interface, samsung-s8

As screen height of samsung s8 is quite large.My images in LoginUI(attached) were looking small.I calculated phone's height in dp programmatically.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        Log.d("checkheightdp",dpHeight+"");
```

It gave me dpheight 692.So,I create a separate layout-h692dp and put my layout with increased image height.For some reason,It is still picking the default layout and hence image not expanding.
My code:
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText email, psd;
public ImageView deleteEmail;
public ImageView deletePsd;
public ImageView contactUs;
GlobalProvider globalProvider;

private int a = 0;
private Button sign_in_button, tourist_in_button;
private List<String> history = new ArrayList<String>();
private String usernameStr, newVersion = "x";
public static String character = "character";

private ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;
private NetworkInfo netInfo;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
public Thread thread;
private BroadcastReceiver myNetReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            netInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo == null) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "网络链接不可用！", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
};






public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    globalProvider = GlobalProvider.getInstance(LoginActivity.this);


    IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(myNetReceiver, mFilter);
    //找到对象email、psd、sign_in_button并绑定监听事件
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    psd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.psd);
    contactUs = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.contact_us);
    sign_in_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    tourist_in_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tourist_in_button);
    deleteEmail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deleteEmail);
    deletePsd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deletePsd);
    //  gview=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
    // ImageAdapter imgAdapter=new ImageAdapter(LoginActivity.this);
    //gview.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
    contactUs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ContactActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    deleteEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    deletePsd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    try {
        findHistoryList();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                deleteEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                deleteEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
    psd.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                deletePsd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                deletePsd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
    deleteEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            email.setText("");
        }
    });
    deletePsd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            psd.setText("");
        }
    });
    sign_in_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (email.getText() == null || email.getText().toString().equals("") || psd.getText() == null || email.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.notempty))
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        }).show();
            } else {
                try {
                    setHistoryList();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loging));
                dialog.show();
                sign_in_button.setEnabled(false);
                loginAction(v);
            }
        }
    });
    //为sign_in_button绑定监听事件，调用loginAction(v)
    tourist_in_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loging));
            dialog.show();
            sign_in_button.setEnabled(false);
            loginActionTourist(v);
        }
    });
}

public static void setCharacter(Context context, String cha) {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(character, cha);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getToken(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String cha = settings.getString(character, ""/*default value is ""*/);
    //Log.v("err", tokenStr);
    return cha;
}

//创建loginAction（）方法
public void loginAction(View view) {
    //分别把email、psd的值传递给usernameStr、passwordStr
    final String usernameStr = email.getText().toString();
    String passwordStr = psd.getText().toString();
    Log.d("checkentries",usernameStr+" "+passwordStr);
    setCharacter(this, "user");
    // Log.d("chkpassword",passwordStr);
    //GlobalProvider.getInstance().character =
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();


    params.put("password", passwordStr);
    params.put("email",usernameStr );


    CustomRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginUrlStr, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Log.d("responsevolley", response.getString("token"));
                dialog.dismiss();
                globalProvider.IsLoging = true;
                sign_in_button.setEnabled(true);

                String token;
                token = response.getString("token");
                token = token.replaceAll("\"", "");//把token中的"\""全部替换成""
                Constants.setToken(LoginActivity.this, token);
                globalProvider.isLogined=true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("isLogin", usernameStr);
                startActivity(intent);
                //this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);//为结果绑定Activity.RESULT_OK
                finish();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("errorvolley", error.toString());

            dialog.dismiss();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.errorId))
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    }).show();
            sign_in_button.setEnabled(true);

        }
    });


    globalProvider.addRequest(jsonObjectRequest);


}


public void loginActionTourist(View view) {


    usernameStr = "guest@veg.com";
    String passwordStr = "12345678";
    setCharacter(this, "tourist");
    globalProvider.isLogined = true;
    // GlobalProvider.getInstance().character = "tourist";

    // 绑定参数
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap();
    params.put("email", usernameStr);
    params.put("password", passwordStr);

    CustomRequest customRequest=new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginUrlStr, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            globalProvider.IsLoging = true;
            tourist_in_button.setEnabled(true);
            String token;
            try {
                token = response.getString("token");
                token = token.replaceAll("\"", "");
                Constants.setToken(LoginActivity.this, token);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //把token中的"\""全部替换成""

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("isLogin", usernameStr);
            startActivity(intent);
            //this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);//为结果绑定Activity.RESULT_OK
            finish();


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.errorId))
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    }).show();
            tourist_in_button.setEnabled(true);

        }
    });
}

private void findHistoryList() throws IOException {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/EasybuyCustomer.txt");

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String s = null;

    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        history.add(s);
        //System.out.println(arrs[0] + " : " + arrs[1] + " : " + arrs[2]);
    }
    if (history.size() > 0) {
        email.setText(history.get(0));
        psd.setText(history.get(1));
    }

    br.close();
    isr.close();
    fis.close();
}

public void setHistoryList() throws IOException {



    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/EasybuyCustomer.txt");
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

    bw.write("");
    bw.write(email.getText().toString());
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write(psd.getText().toString());
    bw.newLine();

    bw.close();
    osw.close();
    fos.close();
}



@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


        View v = getCurrentFocus();

        if (isShouldHideInput(v, ev)) {
            hideSoftInput(v.getWindowToken());
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}


private boolean isShouldHideInput(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v != null && (v instanceof EditText)) {
        int[] l = { 0, 0 };
        v.getLocationInWindow(l);
        int left = l[0], top = l[1], bottom = top + v.getHeight(), right = left
                + v.getWidth();
        if (event.getX() > left && event.getX() < right
                && event.getY() > top && event.getY() < bottom) {

            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void hideSoftInput(IBinder token) {
    if (token != null) {
        InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(token,
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    //按下键盘上返回按钮
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.youconfirmtologout))
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        a=a+1;
                        finish();

                    }
                }).show();

        return true;
    }else{
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(myNetReceiver);
    if(a>0){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    a=0;

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: can you post the code from the Activity that is pulling this layout ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén :posted !Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer,why creating a separate height layout was not working.
Though screen height of samsung s8 is 692 dp,but 25dp is not available as It is used by system UI.
 Apparently it was stated in developer.android.com.

The Android system might use some of the screen for system UI (such as the system bar at the bottom of the screen or the status bar at the top), so some of the screen might not be available for your layout.
Therefore,subtracting 25 dp from 692 gives 667dp.Creating layout-h667dp worked.

I went to this post.
https://medium.com/@elye.project/an-important-note-when-managing-different-screen-height-3140e26e381a